# Mathematically, how do you show that prices follow a lognormal distribution?

Tags: statistics, finance

In finance, the price of an asset is given by the following formula.

r=returns
Pt = Price at time "t".
P0 = Actual Price.

Then.
$r=\ln (\frac{P_t}{P_0})$
We assume that prices are Log-normally distributed $\sim LogN(0,\sigma^2_p)$.

so, the distribution functions
$$
F_r(r) = P(r\le r)=P[(ln(\frac{P_t}{P_0})\le r]=P[P_t\le (P_0e^r)] =F_P(P_0e^y),
$$
thus the density can be found as its derivative w.r.t $y$, i.e.,
$$
f_r(r)=f_P(P_0e^r)*P_0e^r$$
$$=>\frac{P_0e^r}{P_0e^r\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\{-(\ln P_0e^r)^2/(2\sigma^2)\}$$
$$=>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\{(ln(P_0)-r)^2/(2\sigma^2)\},
$$
hence,  $r \sim N(r,\sigma^2)$.

I know that this sequence or derivation is wrong, but I don't know where the error is. I would be very grateful if you could clarify the matter for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you elaborate on $$=>\frac{P_0e^r}{P_0e^r\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\{-(\ln P_0e^r)^2/(2\sigma^2)\}?$$ I don't get this conlcusion. We know that there is an infinitude of financal models where returns ar not normal, and prices not lognormal.

Comment: Yes... We assume that prices are Log-normally distributed. From this assumption it follows that the returns are normally distributed.

Comment: Then why do you think the derivation is wrong and ask us to find the error ?

Comment: Because the theory says that prices are distributed log-normally, but returns [Ln(Pt/P0)] are distributed as a normal with zero mean, but in my calculation I get mean "r".

$$=>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\{(ln(P_0)-r)^2/(2\sigma^2)\},
$$
This expression should have zero mean (have no mean) and the value of "x" should be "r".

Answer (score 1):

When you assume that prices $P_t$ are lognormally distributed you can write this as
$$\tag{1}
P_t=P_0\,e^{\sigma_P W_t-\frac{\sigma_P^2t}{2}}
$$
where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion, i.e. $W_t\sim N(0,t)$. This ensures
$$
\mathbb E[P_t]=P_0\,,\quad \operatorname{Var}[P_t]=P_0^2\big(e^{2\sigma_p^2 t}-1\big)\,.
$$
Then the return
$$
\ln(P_t/P_0)=\sigma_P W_t-\frac{\sigma_P^2 t}{2}
$$
is clearly normally distributed with mean $-\frac{\sigma_P^2 t}{2}$.

If you want the return to be normally distributed with mean zero you can achieve it in this framework by assuming that the price is
$$\tag{2}
P_t=P_0\,e^{\sigma_P W_t}
$$
which leads to
$$
\mathbb E[P_t]=P_0\,e^\frac{\sigma_P^2 t}{2}\,,\quad \operatorname{Var}[P_t]=P_0^2\big(e^{2\sigma_P^2 t}-e^{\sigma_P^2 t}\big).
$$

Comment: mmm.. Sure. In this case it presents a new model (in my opinion). However, I am considering the model $P_t = P_0*e^r$.  If we consider this model, the theory assumes that the returns (r) will follow a normal distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. So the prices (Pt) will follow a LogNormal, but I don't know what their mean and variance are.

Comment: The model (1) is -under the names of Black, Scholes and Merton- several decades old. The expectations of $P_t$ I had written in the first version of the answer. The variances I added just now.