# Variance of Stock Price - St - given by GBM

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, finance

I am working on a problem, where I'm interested in computing the variance of the stock price in the next two years.

Using the GBM notation for the stock price,

I can write St as

$
S_t = S_0e^{(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W_t}
$

I have already calculated $E[St] = S_0e^{\mu t}$

Taking Variance as

$
Var[S_t] = E[S_T^2] - E[S_T]^2
$, I am having difficulties with $E[S_T^2]$

Currently, I have written it as:

$
E[S_T^2] = E[S_0^2e^{2(\mu - \frac {\sigma^2}{2})t + 2\sigma W_t}]
$

Taking the constant variables out, I would have:

$
E[S_T^2] = S_0e^{2 \mu - \sigma^2T}E[e^{2 \sigma W_t}] 
$,

however this is not the same as what the results are suggesting, which show

$
E[S_T^2] = S_0e^{2\mu T + \sigma T}E[e^{\frac{-2 \sigma}{2T}+ 2\sigma Wt}]$.

I am not sure how I could reach the value that is in the solutions and any pointers would be appreciated. I am also not sure why the $\frac{-2 \sigma}{2T}$ is still in the expectations in the solutions, as I think it would make sense to have it outside, given that it is a constant.

Comment: To use subscripts in MathJax, you should use an underscore: i.e. `S_T` to get $S_T$,

Comment: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439642/mathematically-how-do-you-show-that-prices-follow-a-lognormal-distribution/4439703?noredirect=1#comment9297334_4439703) contains the formula for the variance. The trick is to find $E[e^{2X}]$ from $1=E[e^{2X-\operatorname{Var}[2X]/2}]=E[e^{2X}]e^{-\operatorname{Var}[2X]/2}=E[e^{2X}]e^{-2\operatorname{Var}[X]}$.